# Map scalar-valued SQL function to method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

Inside a `DbContext` class, I try to map a methood to a SQL scalar function.
The only documentation I can find about this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping

Where can I find the full documentation about this?

I tried something like this, but I always get the exception I throw inside that function. Can I get more details about what is wrong?

```
[DbFunction]
public static double CalcAmount(int Company, string Item, double Quantity)
    => throw new Exception();
```

The name is the same as the SQL function. I also tried addding the schema and function name in the attribute and added the function with modelbuilder, but nothing works.

Also the SQL permissions are not a problem.

Is only the name important? Is double vs float a problem? (I tried both)

Can I use the function anywhere? I tried using it in a LINQ query.

**Update:**

I used the function like this:

```
from t in ctx.MyTable 
select new { t, amount=MyDbContext.CalcAmount(1, "123", 2)}
```

If instead I use it like this:

```
from t in ctx.MyTable 
select new { t.Prop1, t.Prop2, amount=MyDbContext.CalcAmount(1, "123", 2)}
```

Then it works.
See the comments of Ivan Stoev

Comment: Unfortunately the link you included is the only documentation of this feature. Where is your `CalcAmount` method located? Note that if it's not inside your derived `DbContext` class, it requires explicit configuration on order to be included in the model. Also note that such function can be used only inside LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: It's in a DbContext derived class: from t in ctx.MyTable select new { t, amount=MyDbContext.CalcAmount(1, "123", 2)}

Comment: I see. Most likely the problem is that the sample query causes client evaluation, and the function is supposed to be translated to SQL. If you change select clause like this `new { t.SomeProp1, t.SomeProp2, amount = …}` , it should work. i.e. selecting a whole entity `t` plus something causes something to be evaluated client side. EF Core defect.

Comment: yes!! Now it works!!

Comment: Thanks for the help! If you add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the [DbFunction] tag with parameters if the error is not clear:

```
[DbFunction(FunctionName = "TEST_FUNCTION", Schema = "test")]
```

using your db schema and the function name